# Create D3 Stack Chart with inclusive values

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, stacked-chart

I want to modify the [basic side bar chart](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/bar/2/) to be a stack bar chart, which will reflect partial-amount:total relationship. I already created a `matrix` with the following:

```
[{y:0, x0:221, x1:1670},
 {y:1, x0:581, x1:1473},
 {y:2, x0:2485, x1:2643},
 {y:3, x0:135, x1:8714},
 {y:4, x0:31, x1:211}]
```

For reference, in each case the true total would be `x0` + `x1`.

I have a normal bar chart for the totals, but I cannot understand how to convert it to a stacked chart. Also, if there is a way to accomplish this without mutating the data (subtracting `x0` from the true total to get `x1`), that would also be ideal.

Existing BarChart

```
// Constants
var width = 450,
    barHeight = 20,
    height = 300,
    padding = 10,
    leftMargin = 10;

var typeBarChart = d3.select('.typeBarChart')
  .attr('width', width)
  .attr('height', barHeight*dataGroupByType.length); // dataGroupByType is a D3 nest data series with length is 5

// X-axis; 
var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, maxCrime]) // maxCrime determine elsewhere, approx. 8850
    .range([0, width]);

var chart = d3.select(".typeBarChart")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", barHeight * dataGroupByType.length);

var bar = chart.selectAll("g")
    .data(dataGroupByType)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * barHeight + ")"; });

bar.append("rect")
    .attr("width", function(d) { return x(d.values); })
    .attr("height", barHeight - 1);

bar.append("text")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      if (d.values < 1000) {
        return x(d.values) + 20;
      } else {
        return x(d.values) - 3;
      }
    })
    .attr("y", barHeight / 2)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .text(function(d) { return d.values; });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a some issues with the code template.... 
I refined few to create a simplest stacked bar graph.. this would help you get started...

*Working fiddle:* https://jsfiddle.net/egmf47ne/

**CODE:**

**HTML**

```
<div class ="typeBarChart"></div>
```

**JS**

```
var _data = [{y:0, x0:221, x1:1670},
 {y:1, x0:581, x1:1473},
 {y:2, x0:2485, x1:2643},
 {y:3, x0:135, x1:8714},
 {y:4, x0:31, x1:211}]

// Constants
var width = 450,
    barHeight = 20,
    height = 300,
    padding = 10,
    leftMargin = 10;

var typeBarChart = d3.select('.typeBarChart')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width', width)
  .attr('height', barHeight*_data.length); 

var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, 8850]) // maxCrime
    .range([0, width]);

var bar = typeBarChart.selectAll("g")
    .data(_data)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * barHeight + ")"; });

bar.append("rect")
        .attr("fill","blue") // blue bars of x0 + x1
    .attr("width", function(d) { return x(d.x0 + d.x1); })
    .attr("height", barHeight - 1);

bar.append("rect")
        .attr("fill","red")  // red bars of x0 only
    .attr("width", function(d) { return x(d.x0); })
    .attr("height", barHeight - 1);
```

Comment: Hi Taran, I like your solution to stack the smaller rectangles on top of the larger one. Thank you!
Side question: is it possible to add a transition to the set of red rectangles so that they fill in with a bit of flair?

Comment: hey, try using .transition().duration(time) on the red rectangles. have initial width as 0, and final width as stated above